# Powershell Script for TFS Build Definition

Tags: tfs, build-process

I am trying to create a powershell script to create TFS build definition. I this example in C# to create it (http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/04/26/creating-a-build-definition-using-the-tfs-2010-api.aspx). However, I am having trouble creating a build definition.

My Script:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $buildName,`enter code here`
[string] $teamProject="Templates",
[string] $buildTemplateName = "TestBuildTemplate",
[string] $buildDescription = "Test Descirption",
[string] $buildController = "TFS - Controller"
)

Clear-Host

$ErrorActionPreference = “Stop” ;
if ($Verbose) { $VerbosePreference = “Continue” ; }

$assemblylist = 
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client",
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow",
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client",
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common",
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client"

Write-Verbose -Message “Loading TFS Build assembly…”

foreach ($asm in $assemblylist)
{
    $asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($asm)
}

 $tfsCollectionUrl = "TFS Server IP Address"

 $server.EnsureAuthenticated()
 if(!$server.HasAuthenticated)
 {
    Write-Host "Failed to authenticate TFS"
    exit
 }

 Write-Host "Connected to TFS...."

 $buildServer = $server.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])

 $def = $buildserver.CreateBuildDefinition($teamProject)
 $def.Name = $buildTemplateName
 $def.Description = $buildDescription


 $def.Workspace.AddMapping("$/Default/Sampleapplication1", '"$(SourceDir)"', 0)
 $def.Workspace.AddMapping('"$/OtherPath/"', "", 1)

 $def.BuildController = $buildserver.GetBuildController($buildController)
 $def.DefaultDropLocation = "Drop Location Share"


 $def.Save()
```

The error i am getting is unable to save as Process is not defined. What I am I missing here?

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory, you seemed to have missed the whole section from the blog under the heading **Process**. The process definition (which projects to build) is mandatory to save the build def, exactly as it would be when doing it through the UI.

Comment: I should have been more accurate in my question. I tried to implement the process section as shown in the blog. But I have trouble in the WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters); and BuildSettings settings = newBuildSettings();  sections. One of the errors I am getting is "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when I code the "varprocess = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters); " section. I am not sure what is happening here or my script is wrong. I am looking for a example in how to write that.